# Getting the related posts from specific category (category/_posts)

Tags: jekyll

I am doing the following

```
{% for post in site.related_posts limit:3 %}
   // My stuff
{% endfor %}
```

and it keeps returning the posts from each of my categories i.e. `blog/_posts/` as well as `projects/_posts/` what I want is only `blog` posts. So I tried to do the following

```
{% for post in site.categories.blog.related_posts limit:3 %}
    // My stuff
{% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't seem to return anything at all. Can any one please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never use related_posts, but this fairly ugly bit might work for you:

capture the category

```
{% capture related_posts %}{{ page.categories }}{% endcapture %}
```

Use that category to create your related posts

```
{% assign collection = site.categories[related_posts] %}
```

Return the related posts in a loop, pulling out the current page's post

```
{% for article in collection %}
 {% unless page.url == article.url %}
  {{ article.title }} - {{ category | capitalize }}<br />
 {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

Both this and related posts are processor intensive if you have a lot of posts.